# send two variables via ajax/json

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I tried to send two variables via ajax/json but something gone wrong.

first:

```
var searchbox = $(this).val();

var datastring = 'searchword='+ searchbox;
```

second:

```
<?php $lang = $_GET[lang]; ?>
```

ajax/json:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "files/search.php",
    data: dataString+"&lang=<?php $lang ?>",
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
    ...(etc)
```

on search.php page I need:

```
$searchrequest = $_POST['searchword'];

$lang = $_POST['lang'];
```

and `$searchrequest` works, but $lang don't use transfered data.

I tried to make Array of this two data and others, but nothing. 
Can some help or tell better way to do this?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing it this way. Pass it to `.ajax()` as an object so that jQuery encodes everything properly. Also, you should encode the value before echoing it out in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a string to access the array fields:

```
<?php $lang = $_GET['lang']; ?>
```

and you have to `echo` the value contained in `$lang`:

```
 data: dataString+"&lang=<?php echo $lang ?>",
```

But if the string in `$lang` contains any other unsafe URI character (most likely not as you are getting it from `$_GET`, but still) you have to use the `escpape` function:

```
data: dataString+"&lang=" + escape('<?php echo $lang ?>'),
```

or even better (also encodes `searchbox` properly:

```
data: {searchword: searchbox, lang: "<?php echo $lang ?>"},
```

Alternatively, you can send the variable via GET by appending it to the URL:

```
url: "files/search.php?lang=<?php echo $lang ?>",
```

Comment: Sorry, I miss echo when I type this here. I tried it, nothing :)

Comment: @Filip Krstic: Does `$lang` have a value at all? Is the Ajax code in the same file where you have `$lang = $_GET['lang'];`?

Comment: Yes, it has, and yes it is. 
Link is:
http://www.example.com/index.php?id=1&lang=en, and $lang have value on index.php page, but when it gone via $.ajax, and when I want to use it in search.php value is empty.

Comment: King, thanks at all. All two methods works! 

data: {searchword: searchbox, lang: "<?php echo $lang ?>"},
and
url: "files/search.php?lang=<?php echo $lang ?>",

Answer (score 1):

This code you used:

```
<?php $lang ?>
```

Does not print anything. You need to

```
<?php echo $lang; ?>
```